# Characters not displaying correctly (HTML encoded) in Android app

Tags: bug, status-norepro, android-app, unicode

I've just found this, in the main screen. Some characters are shown HTML-formatted (á,é,í,ó,ú...).
[image: screen shot]

Comment: [Not repro'd](http://i.stack.imgur.com/R641G.png) on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app v1.0.82 (beta). Not sure if it has been fixed, or device-dependent bug.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be fixed.  The likely culprit was a that the truncation method didn't have `preventBisectedHtmlEntities` set so instead of becoming `expresi&#243;n ...` it became `expresi&#243...`.